# Updating the price on product page when variations are chosen with WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having a couple of issues with displaying an updated price for a product on the product page itself using WooCommerce.

Basically we have a custom builder page that allows the user to select different options (or variations in this case) and then when they add it to their cart the correct price is calculated. That all works fine.

The problem I'm having is that we want to display the price on screen as they change their options around.

So, let's say I've picked a Blue Item that is 6 meters long, the price should be £100, but if I choose the Red Item that is 1 meter long, the price is £10.

I'm guessing a bit of jQuery or something could dynamically update the page, but I'm at a loss to know where or how I do this.

It would need to fire a function I'm assuming on change of a form select box.

Currently, I'm displaying the price using this...

```
$product = new WC_Product(538);

echo esc_attr($product->get_price());
```

I think that's wrong anyway as that's the base price rather than the variation price, but either way, I still need to find a way to update the price on the screen WITHOUT refreshing.

Here is one of my SELECT form items, though there are quite a few of these on the page.

```
<select id="frame-depth" class="kad-select" name="attribute_frame-depth" data-attribute_name="attribute_frame-depth"" data-show_option_none="yes">
<option value="Standard depth"  selected="selected">Standard depth</option>
<option value="Extra Deep" >Extra Deep</option>
</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If I need to update the question with any more detail, I can do so. I just thought I'd keep it simple!

Simon

Comment: Hey @Simon Facing the same challenge :( have you found any solution to it? it must be a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it roughly like this in JS, making use of the `found_variation` event:

```js
var currentVariation = null;

function calcTotalPrice(variation = null) {
  if (variation) {
    currentVariation = variation;
  }
  if (!currentVariation) {
    var $price = $('#product-price');
    if ($price && $price.length) {
      currentVariation = {
        display_price: $price.val()
      };
    }
  }
  if (currentVariation) {
    var qty = $('#quantity').val();
    var total = currentVariation.display_price * qty;
    $('#total-price-result').html('€ ' + number_format(total, 2, ',', ' '));
  }
}

$('form.variations_form').on('found_variation', function(e, variation) {
  calcTotalPrice(variation);
});
$('#quantity').on('input change', function() {
  calcTotalPrice();
});
$('form.variations_form').on('hide_variation', function() {
  $('#total-price-div').hide();
});
$('form.variations_form').on('show_variation', function() {
  $('#total-price-div').show();
});
```

And on the HTML/template side I override `woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` and edit the pricing part to be similar to this:

```html
<div id="total-price-div">
    <h4><label>{{ __("Total", "my-text-domain") }}</label></h4>
    <div class="value">
        <span class="total-price"><span id="total-price-result" class="total-price"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this can help someone?